# Add a two column above div but that column and div should not have gap

Tags: html, css, notepad++, brackets

In div class background color is black, My question is make a two column in  anyway so that the div class of horizontal line should not have gap while making a column.
Suppose i create a two column first and after i make a div class, the output will be shown the gap between column and div , I don't want that gap

```html
<div class="right-div" style="background-color:black">
    <table border="2px" style="background-color:red">
        <tr>
            <th bgcolor="#339A99"><font color="white">S.NO</font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#339A99"><font color="white">Course</font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#339A99"><font color="white">Duration</font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#339A99"><font color="white">Credit Hours</font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#339A99"><font color="white">No. Of Learners</font></th>
            <th bgcolor="#339A99"><font color="white">Action</font></th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
            <td></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</div>
```

Comment: If you're planning on using regex in Notepad++ for complex HTML manipulation then...don't.  Use a tool which can parse your HTML.

Comment: Most of these attributes are deprecated in HTML5.